# Who is Hearty Fiberstein?

Tags: analysis, tripping-the-rift-movie

In [Tripping The Rift: The Movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1212448/), when Whip is selecting a brain from the shelf (obviously mocking Mel Brook's [Young Frankenstein](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072431/?ref_=sr_1)), we see the following labels on the jars.

1. Genius ~ Albert Einstein's Brain
2. Senator ~ Diane Finestein's Brain
3. Comedy ~  Mel Brookstein's Brain
4. Broadway ~ Hearty Fiberstein's Brain

I get who first three are (who wouldn't get the first one?), but who is Hearty Fiberstein supposed to be mocking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a parody of [Harvey Fierstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_Fierstein)'s name.

> American actor and playwright, noted for the distinction of winning
>   Tony Awards for both writing and originating the lead role in his
>   long-running play Torch Song Trilogy, about a gay drag-performer and
>   his quest for true love and family, as well as writing the
>   award-winning book to the musical La Cage aux Folles. He has since
>   become a champion for gay civil rights.

Here's a news story about him on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnPiKjzTi3Y).